# Datasource creation failed using PCF User Provided Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle12c, cloud-foundry

I have a `SpringBoot` application and deploying it in `PCF` where app is trying to connect Oracle 12c Database using `PCF User Provided Services` but it failing with this error `Failed to determine a suitable driver class`

`build.gradle` code:

[image]

and here are the configuration that I used in CUP service:
[image]

Service binding is happening properly. I can see the same details under `VCAP_SERVICES` in `Environment Variables`.

Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**: I think you want the `uri` to be `oracle://..`. Strip off the `jdbc:` part. The Spring Autoreconfiguration code that gets injected by the Java buildpack will look at the prefix on the URI, so it needs `oracle://` to know it's an Oracle link.

**Long Answer**: You probably don't want to depend on the injected Spring Autoreconfiguration. When it just works, it's great, but it can be difficult to understand what it's doing when it doesn't work.

It is better to use Spring Cloud Connector or even better, as all signs point to this replacing Spring Cloud Connector, use [java-cfenv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv). For details on java-cfenv, see [this blog post](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv).

Spring Cloud Connector has the same issue I mentioned above as the Spring Autoreconfiguration, except that it will pretty clearly tell you when it doesn't recognize a bound service. Anyway, if you decide to use SCC, make sure you prefix the URI with `oracle://`.

If you use `java-cfenv`, it's more flexible so it's really up to you what properties and values you inject through the service.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have tried changing the connection string to start with `oracle://` but same error. I'll give a try to java-cfenv,